# Send Childs in Woocommerce REST API categories endpoint

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

How can I add extra data to the product categories endpoint?
I can update products endpoint by applying the filter `woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object`

Can't seem to find the function to apply a filter for the categories endpoint.

This is how I am modifying the products endpoint:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'custom_change_product_response', 20, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_variation_object', 'custom_change_product_response', 20, 3);

function custom_change_product_response($response, $object, $request) {
    $response->data['custom_field'] = "Custom Data";
    return $response;
}
```

I want to send all the children to the `/products/categories` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I just found it after a lot of searching.
I had to modify the filter method :

```
return apply_filters( "woocommerce_rest_prepare_{$this->taxonomy}", $response, $item, $request );
```

Here the taxonomy for categories is: `product_cat`

So to add data you have to use the filter:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_cat', 'custom_change_category_response', 20, 3);
```

And for sending child categories we will use:

```
$catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    'orderby' => 'ASC', 
    'child_of'=> $id 
    ));
```

So the whole code is like this:

```
function custom_change_category_response($response, $object, $request) {
     
    $id = $response->data['id'];
    // Get subcategories of the current category
    $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    'orderby' => 'ASC', 
    'child_of'=> $id 
    ));
    
    $response->data['children_count'] = count($catTerms);
    $response->data['childs_array'] = $catTerms;
    return $response;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_cat', 'custom_change_category_response', 20, 3);
```